# beginner :While loop not working as it should

Tags: c++, loops, vector, while-loop

I am still a beginner and I am learning from a book. There was a drill that asked me filter input based on a vector of filtered words and if it was one of them it outputs "bad word"

Here is the drill exactly as in the book.

> Try This
>   Write a program that “bleeps” out words that you don’t like; that is, you read in words using cin and print them again on cout. If a word is among a few you have defined, you write out BLEEP instead of that word. Start with one “disliked word” such as string disliked = “Broccoli”
>   When that works, add a few more.;

Here is the code I wrote:

```
#include <D:\std_lib_facilities.h>

int main()
{

    // RL: omitting actual "bad" words to protect the innocent...
    vector <string> bwords { "word1", "word2", "word3" };

    vector <string> words;
    string input = "";

    while(cin >> input)
    {
        words.push_back(input);
    }

    double counter1 = 0;
    double counter2 = 0;

    while(counter1 < bwords.size() && counter2 < words.size())
    {
        if(bwords[counter1] == words[counter2])
        {
            cout << " bad word ";
        }
        else if (counter1 == bwords.size() - 1 && counter2 != words.size() )
        {
            cout << " "<< words[counter2] <<" ";
            counter1 = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            ++counter1;
            counter2 += 1 / bwords.size();
        }
    }
}
```

whenever it starts it just tests the first word and repeats its self as if just tests the first if condition.

Comment: Did you step through the code in a debugger, and example the flow and variable values, or print out the values of the counters, location in if statements, etc.?  Learning how to debug is just as important as learning the language.

Comment: counter1 and counter2 are incrementing only when you fall in the else.
If the first work you check is bad, then it will never increment and look for the next

Comment: I haven't looked at the code in detail, but the first thing that struck me is why read all the input words into a vector then go through that?  Why not read a word, check it, produce the appropriate output, then loop to read the next word?  And put the code that checks if a word is bad or not into a function. Then you end up with two dead simple loops (at most) - one in the function that checks if a word is bad or not (note that you might not need a loop here depending on if you're allowed to use a container other than `vector`) and the main loop that calls the function for each input word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You over-complicated your loop.  Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

// RL: omitting actual "bad" words to protect the innocent...
const vector <string> bwords { "word1", "word2", "word3" };

string bleepWordIfBad(const string &word)
{
    if (std::find(bwords.begin(), bwords.end(), word) != bwords.end())
        return "BLEEP";
    else
        return word;
}

int main()
{    
    vector <string> words;
    string input;

    while (cin >> input)
        words.push_back(input);

    for (int counter = 0; counter < words.size(); ++counter)
        cout << " " << bleepWordIfBad(words[counter]) << " ";

    /*
    Alternatively:

    for (vector<string>::iterator iter = words.begin(); iter != words.end(); ++iter)
        cout << " " << bleepWordIfBad(*iter) << " ";
    */

    /*
    Alternatively:

    for (const string &word : words)
        cout << " " << bleepWordIfBad(word) << " ";
    */

    return 0;
}
```

Or, get rid of the manual loop altogether:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

// RL: omitting actual "bad" words to protect the innocent...
const vector <string> bwords { "word1", "word2", "word3" };

string bleepWordIfBad(const string &word)
{
    if (std::find(bwords.begin(), bwords.end(), word) != bwords.end())
        return "BLEEP";
    else
        return word;
}

void outputWord(const string &word)
{
    cout << " " << bleepWordIfBad(word) << " ";
}

int main()
{    
    vector <string> words;
    string input;

    while (cin >> input)
        words.push_back(input);

    for_each(words.begin(), words.end(), outputWord);

    /*
    Alternatively:

    for_each(words.begin(), words.end(),
        [](const string &word) { cout << " " << bleepWordIfBad(word) << " "; }
    );
    */

    return 0;
}
```

Or, get rid of the input `vector` altogether and just filter the user's input as it is being entered:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

// RL: omitting actual "bad" words to protect the innocent...
const vector <string> bwords { "word1", "word2", "word3" };

string bleepWordIfBad(const string &word)
{
    if (std::find(bwords.begin(), bwords.end(), word) != bwords.end())
        return "BLEEP";
    else
        return word;
}

int main()
{    
    string word;

    while (cin >> word)
        cout << " " << bleepWordIfBad(word) << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for pointing me to the other sub-functions of vectors as the only one written in the book is the size() sub-function at least for now

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of variations!

Comment: @StilesCrisis: welcome to C++, where there are dozens of different ways to accomplish the same thing! :)

Comment: LOL, I've been writing C++ professionally for 15 years. I was more speaking to the amount of effort you spent on your post :)